# VPS to replace MobileMe or Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, vps, self-hosting

All,

Yes, this has been touched on in other questions, but I can't find something similar enough.

I currently have Google Apps hosting personal email, calendars, contacts, etc. I do like the other google services, but they're outside of Apps. One of the little google irritations that I have to maintain a separate account for Picassa, etc.

So, I'm thinking about moving myself away from Google, but purely for personal, privacy type issues. Do I really like the ads, the email snooping, etc? I've had, and liked MobileMe, back when it was iTools, and then .Mac, but it doesn't offer that much really.

How easily can I replicate it all on a VPS? I don't want to host it myself at home, I'd lose all the wonderful datacenter goodness. THis isn't about personal geekery in my own basement, just about taking a little control back from Google.

So, email is fine running an IMAP server, a nice front-end, etc.

What about Calendars and Contacts?

And, how easily can it be setup to sync to the desktop and iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paying for a hosted Exchange service will give you immediate push-email on Outlook for Mac and your iPhone, with calendar, contacts, tasks and notes.  It's worth considering, as this combination can do everything that Google Apps can, as well as a lot more.

Comment: Yes, great idea, thank you. The only thing that lacks is the actual webhosting - I was thinking of replacing Picassa with a self-hosted Gallery2 site.

Comment: @Alex: You can use image hosting services like Flickr and SmugMug, but if you want to do it yourself, you can get decent free web hosting at places like Byet http://www.byethost.com/. You can use subdomains with A Records pointing mail.alex.com to your mailserver (just for Outlook Web App) and photos.alex.com to your image hosting for example.

Comment: Or, you may find hosted Exchange packages that come with some web space as well.

Comment: Thanks - you've sold me on that as a good idea and something to seriously investigate.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say CNAME Records before.  Cheers.